# I'm Trying to Find the Race that's basically a Lizardfolk-Centaur?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, races, product-identification

I swear I've seen a drawing of what I can only describe as a Lizardfolk-Centaur.  Where it's a Lizardfolk's near-term w/ 2 arms on top and what looks like a large monitor lizard's body w/ 4 clawed, reptilian legs & feet.  I think it's called a "Dracotaur", but I'm not completely sure that's what they're called.

When I typed in "Dracotaur" into Google Images, I was rewarded with these images, which makes me believe this race or monster is detailed somewhere.

- http://beyondheroes2.altervista.org/dracotaur.jpg
- http://rs252.pbsrc.com/albums/hh32/J_Cortez83/sketchbook/dracotaur.jpg~320x480
- (Naturally neither of the pages those images were found in had any
  info regarding the original source)

Does anyone know what I'm talking about? If I'm not making this up, what's this creature called and which book is it in? I think I remember it being in an official Paizo Pathfinder book, but it could also be a 3rd-Party publisher as well.

Can anyone help me out here?

Many thanks!

Comment: I have no idea what that is, but it sounds *awesome*.

Comment: In the future, you can perform a reverse image search using the image without context that you found. Behold: https://goo.gl/a4ZO9F

Comment: @heathenJesus that's amazing. I knew of image searches like that, I guess I never actually saw any use for it..... Until now! Awesome too!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

These are, indeed, dracotaurs. They were published in D&D 3.5's Monster Manual 3. An excerpt from it with their description can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20161101202138/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/iw/20040815b&page=5).

They're also present in D&D 4e's MM2 as drakkoths.

Comment: But, not in Pathfinder.

Answer (score 5):

The Pathfinder version of these is called the **Zothian**, found in Pathfinder module *J3 - Crucible of Chaos* and sourced from Green Ronin's *Advanced Bestiary*.

Top of their stat block starts:

> Zothians, Saurian Centaurs (8) CR 4
>
> N Large monstrous humanoid
>
> Advanced Bestiary 213

Pathfinder gives them the name "Zothians," in Advanced Bestiary they are just a "Saurian Centaur" (centaur with the saurian template), found on p.247 of the Pathfinder compatible version of Advanced Bestiary (as an example in the Saurian template entry, but they even have a pic). In the module they live integrated within the lizardfolk community. They're also available in Hero Lab if you have bought the Advanced Bestiary data pack (which I've found to be a good investment because Paizo loves sourcing monsters out of there, they're the rare bird that actually uses other third party OGL in their products!).

Answer (score -2):

Spelljammer had a race called a Dracon that was awesome and might be what you are remembering.

Comment: Can you describe the Dracon more so others can tell what its characteristics are, more than just "probably pretty similar to a lizardfolk-centaur"?

Comment: This answer would be improved by indicating which book it was in, which version it was from, and whether it was ever available in nay way for PCs.

Answer (score -2):

Related, but not-Pathfinder this made me think of [Zoats](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Zoat) in Warhammer 40k; a lizardlike alien centaur race - might be of interest.